# Prevent Content Jumping Below Image as it Loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have an image that I am giving 100% width.  The issue I am noticing is that while the image loads, the content below jumps up to where the image sits while it loads. I know I need to give the image some sort of fixed height, but I want the image to remain responsive.  The desired effect: The image looks exactly as it does when applying 100% width and prevents the content below from jumping while the image loads. Please advise on this. My code is as follows:

```
<img src={"https://storage.googleapis.com/youfit-assets/239315_66400_YouFit_JUL21_Mil_Website_1680x761_CarInitial.jpg"}
  alt="travel"
  className="image"/>
```

Styles:

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

In order to duplicate what I am seeing test on an incognito browser with the following link https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-montalcini-ohts8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Well it is hard for the browser to know the height until it loads. Did you try setting a min-height? You could add an event listener onload to remove a class that sets the min height

Comment: Do you know what the aspect ratio is?

Comment: I believe 1680x760

Comment: @epascarello I like that idea as well

Comment: `width: 100%;
  height: 45.2vw;`

Comment: @epascarello that's not going to look good on bigger desktop's, etc tho.  I can't really give it a fixed height

Comment: I’m not sure if this is *correct* for React, but adding `width="1680" height="761"` to the img tag in your code sandbox pushes the text down to its position before the image loads, so no jumping once the image is loaded. The width and height attributes tells the display how much room (width & height) to allocate. The browser figures out the scalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your img tag into div, so it should look like:

```
<div className="image-wrapper">
    <img src={...} alt="travel" className="image"/>
</div>
<div style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>TEXT BELOW</div>
```

then replace your style for image with this style (if your aspect ratio is 4:3):

```
.image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 37.5%;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or if your aspect ratio is 16:9

```
.image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How did you come up with the calculations on what percentage of padding to provide based on the aspect ratio.  Just for my learning

Comment: The problem you were faced with is calling 'layout shift', so in this case you have to know the AR and lets say it's 16:9, so I just calculated it like: 9/16 * 100 = 56.25. The second example with AR of 4:3 I found in this link: [https://dreisbach.us/articles/prevent-jumps-while-image-loading/](https://dreisbach.us/articles/prevent-jumps-while-image-loading/)

Comment: this doesn't work for tiny images like 48x48 px, do you know how to support all image sizes?